# SQL Server: Bulk Insert a CSV file from FTP server

Tags: sql-server, csv, ftp

I need to bulk insert the records from a CSV file located on a FTP server into a table in SQL server. I know I can do the bulk insert like this:

```
GO

BULK
INSERT #dataTMP
FROM 'c:\myFTPDir\filename.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

However instead of reading the file locally, can I do this from the FTP server instead? How can I do this in Microsoft SQL server only in T-SQL?

Comment: From TSQL you can't access FTP directly.  You can use an Agent job to download the file to a local drive and then run the BULK INSERT.

Comment: Are there and other sql server means that can help me download the file to a local drive then? I'm not sure what you mean by an Agent job?

Comment: A [SQL Server Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent) job can run a batch script or a powershell script to download the file, and then a TSQL step to BULK INSERT it.

Answer (score 0):

Try researching SQL Server Integrated Services (SSIS).

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2884/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-ftp-task-for-data-exchange/

Answer (score 0):

BULK INSERT is one of the ways to import CSV files to SQL Server but it does not work with an FTP source. Alternatively, you can use Skyvia and it’s free to try. It accepts various data sources and locations such as FTP.
You need to create 2 connectors: one for SQL Server and the other for the CSV file in an FTP path.
SQL Server Connector
Select SQL Server and specify the credentials and the database to connect to.

[image: mssql-source-skyvia]

CSV in FTP Connector
Select FTP and specify the host and credentials.

[image: ftp-source-skyvia]

Then, create an import process from FTP to SQL Server.

[image: ftp-mssql-package-skyvia]

For more details, check out the article [here](https://skyvia.com/blog/3-easy-ways-to-import-csv-file-to-sql-server)